# Providing more option in a table without context menu

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, contextmenu, desktop-application

In my latest project I've been heavily using popup menu in all table views. The complete desktop application is written in java swing. In the whole application maximum of the reports are in table. Please have a look at the image I've uploaded. All the windows are full of compact data and complex calculations. As all the data is related to each other I've to link them using popup menu. But my client is not satisfied with the pop menu. Because--

1. Most of the time they use only laptops without mouse.
2. They complains me that people/other employees may not know that the table can have a popup menu or he'll not right click to get more options.
3. They use to complain me that it is not an user friendly interface. (After all they are not satisfied.)

I've two questions:

1. Is it really not an user friendly interface?
2. Is there any way or alternative to context menu, so that when user clicks on the table he can see the more options? (in Java Swing)

(Please Note: I can add some buttons on the top of the window and programmatically show or hide them when the table row gets or loses focus. But It will not solve my problem. Because I cannot add more than 5-6 buttons in a row. Using toolbar only with icon is neither a solution. Buttons only icons without text will never be accepted by my client.)

Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Is it really not an user friendly interface?

All GUI's should be designed so that the user can use either the mouse or the keyboard to invoke functions of the GUI.

It is more efficient to use the keyboard so advanced user typically will use this option. Beginners tend to use the mouse.

> Is there any way or alternative to context menu,

Ask the user what they want.

First of all at the very least the menu items of the popup menu should contain "mnemonics" so the functions of the popup can be invoked using the keyboard once the popup is displayed.

Then maybe all you need to add is a `KeyStroke` to display the popup menu instead of using the mouse.

Or, maybe they want a `JMenuBar` with a `JMenu` and `JMenuItem`. Then you can assign "accelearators" to each menu item so the `Action` can be invoked using the keyboard.

Read the [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for more Swing basics and examples. Maybe sections on:

1. How to Use Menus
2. How to Use Key Bindings

will give you some ideas.